# Breach injection through shadow root

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, javascript-injection, html-injections

I'm not a JS programmer. I don't have enough skill to test it myself, so asking for help.
Is it possible to inject script or HTML tag into `shadow_root` element to check for holes on web?

For example `<script>alert("alert");</script>`

Maybe something else like by using `<content>`?

Main question: Is it possible or not?

And additional question: How?

Comment: It is possible to inject content, there are thousand ways to do it... Gives us more details on what you are trying to achieve please.

Comment: What do you mean by "*to check for holes on web*"?

Comment: @Salketer
Like I said in example. Trying to verify that u can throw some code into elements which are under shadow_root. And code will be executed as if it was in any other ordinary text field.
Like: You have an unprotected text field, u throw JS script there, it shows a hole in ur code. Is it possible to do the same if text field element is under shadow root DOM.

Comment: Well, client-side code can be injected anywhere... It can even be ran without being injected just using the console. But that wouldn't do any damage if you validate all user inputs. This question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: @Salketer I know, I'm sorry I cannot say it more specific. But I can tell why do I need that: I have a quest to check web fields, is it possible to inject JS/HTML there or not. And if that's a bit trivial deal then I was interested in confirmation it's not possible if element shadow rooted. Dealing with shadow roots gives me a headache as automation QA.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You want to inject the JS/HTML as the website developper? Or want to inject it as the user? Both are doable, but not the same way. I think you are getting it wrong... If you want to test attack vectors on your website, it's not injecting in the shadow root that you should be concerned about, it is about users saving code to your database, which would then be served to other users... Go to the security stackexchange for that maybe? But really, work on explaining your goal.

Comment: @Salketer As user basicaly. Web there is a big DB. And I have 0 idea how to verify is ur SQL injections are viable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I could dig up in comments, you want to know if your users can inject code in your website pages. The answer is yes, the user has all the rights to play with the DOM in front of him. The easy way is by simply opening your favorite browser's developers' tools.

Do it yourself... Open your developer's tools window here, reach the console and write

```
document.write("<script>alert(\"alert\");</script>");
```

As you can see, you can change anything even directly on StackOverflow. But that causes absolutely no harm to others, just you. While you can do that on SO does mean that it is insecure at all! It is just that your browser has full control on what it received...

Now, the question should be more how can I detect possible points in my application where such injection can be harmful.

The answer is simple, never trust client input. The server should always validate the inputs, and make sure there is no database injection possible. When displaying user provided content, one should also make sure there is no hidden code tag that would be ran by the browser of the users looking at the webpage.

StackOverflow is not suited for this kind of knowledge sharing. I suggest you read about website security in general and then find more in depth resources related to your technology stack and the usage you have with your users' input.

Also, if you are asking this for a real job task you have been given. The most important thing to do would be to tell your manager you are not fit for the task. Not because you lack the talent, but because you lack the knowledge. This shows that you are smart enough to see the task as very important (security IS very important) and you are not willing to play with the company's reputation.

See [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like to know how to best explain that to your superiors.

Comment: Yeah, I know u can change some through DOM or browser console without any consequences. What I mean is influence to the server of course. For example get some data or execute viral script. 
Thanks for the answers. And interesting reading in the link :D